# Flutter error "isn't a type" with imported class

Tags: flutter, dart

I have file models.dart with a few difrent models, one of them is PaidCheckLists. I desided to create folder for each class in it, used json_serializable library to create methods toJson and fromJson for classes that need it, but then something really weird heppend.

In file local_storage.dart in class LocalStorage i can't create variable with PaidCheckLists type, but i imported Paid CheckLists class from folder

```
import 'package:inspector/data/models/paid/paid.dart';
```

but i can create variable with type PaidCheckList in other class, like in bloc class of some of my screen

here you can see how my file are stored

[image]

this is import that i use to create variable with PaidCheckList type in some of my bloc class

```
import 'package:inspector/data/models/paid/paid.dart';
```

this is how this class looks like

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'paid.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class PaidCheckLists {
  List<String> id;
  PaidCheckLists(this.id);

  factory PaidCheckLists.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PaidCheckListsFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PaidCheckListsToJson(this);
}
```

this is other class that i can import in file local_storage.dart

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'logs.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Logs {
  String eventNumber;
  String event;
  String eventDetails;
  String macAdress;
  Logs(this.eventNumber, this.event, this.eventDetails, this.macAdress);
  factory Logs.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$LogsFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$LogsToJson(this);
}
```

Comment: Did you try restarting IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to clean the flutter cache with this command:

```
flutter pub cache repair
```